# php login script always returning false user not found

Tags: php, android, mysqli

I have written a simple php script for android login but i dont know why it is always returning user not found. I debugged my android apk it is fine there but when i checked php script it is always returning false user not found below is my script

```
// i tried echoing everything possible but no outcome
    <?php
    include("conn.php");
    if(isset($_POST['btn_login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    $response = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $username = $row['username'];
        $password = $row['password'];


        $code = "login_success";
        array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"username"=>$username,"password"=>$password));
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else{
        $code = "login_failed";
        $message = "User not found... Please try again";
        array_push($response, array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="text" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="btn_login">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: did you save the plain password in DB? It's a big issue.Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` mechanism to protect your password.

Comment: in registration part i'm using sha1 for password

Comment: Using secure methods is important for your users, saving the actual passwords, even using a just hash. is not sufficient and puts your users at risk. nFor PHP just use `password_hash` and `password_verify` to securely save password verifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Don't use `sha1` to encrypt your password. Always use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) for password encryption and match.

2.Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent your code from `SQL INJECTION`.

3.At the time of the query, you need to use `sha1($password)` instead of `$password`

Change like below:-

```
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
```

***A prepared statement code is given below for help:-***

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
if(isset($_POST['btn_login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1")) {

        /* bind parameters for markers */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username,$password);

        /* execute query */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        /* bind result */
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

        if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) ==1){
            while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
                $username = $row['username'];
                $password = $row['password'];
            }
            $code = "login_success";
            array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"username"=>$username,"password"=>$password));
            echo json_encode($response);
             /* close statement */
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        }else{
            $code = "login_failed";
            $message = "User not found... Please try again";
            array_push($response, array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
            echo json_encode($response);
        }   

    }
}else{
   echo "Please fill form properly!";exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you said that you used sha1 for password, try encode sha1 for `$password` before place into `SELECT`